# Why can't I position my Form?

Tags: html, css, forms

No matter what I have tried, I can not seem to position the form no matter what I have tried.  I have enclosed the form with a DIV to try to position, but it always at the top of the page:  here is my CSS.

```
contactform{
position        : absolute;
left            : 415.50pt;
top             : 345.00pt;
width           : 252.75pt;
height          : 168.00pt;
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="contactForm">
    <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
       <fieldset>
        <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a     comment</legend>
        <p>
        <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
        <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required/>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
        <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required/>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
        <input id="curl" type="url" name="url"/>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
        <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script>
    $("#commentForm").validate();
    </script>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `#`

```
#contactform
{
    position        : absolute;
    left            : 415.50pt;
    top             : 345.00pt;
    width           : 252.75pt;
    height          : 168.00pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you must use # to refer ids and "." to refer classes
else you cant point to the HTML element that you want to manipulate.
Here you miss "#" in CSS
so change your code (CSS)

change from

```
contactform{  
position        : absolute;  
left            : 415.50pt;  
top             : 345.00pt;  
width           : 252.75pt;  
height          : 168.00pt;  
}
```

To,

```
#contactform{  
position        : absolute;  
left            : 415.50pt;  
top             : 345.00pt;  
width           : 252.75pt;  
height          : 168.00pt;  
}
```